# ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end

Tags: compiling

I've been using TekMaker for my book and it has been compiling with no major challenges. This weekend, I started getting the

> !LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

error, and double-checked that I was not using any `\\` commands anywhere; there were none. Since there are nine chapters in the book, I next simply commented all of them out, and the error pointed to same exact line in the same exact chapter, which seems rather odd. I also tried some binary cutting to isolate the offending file.

Any suggestions or guidance. I can post the source files if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: Try deleting the auxiliary files and recompiling.  If you commented out all the code and the problem still points to the same line I would guess it has to something to do with files left over from the previous run - but that is just a guess.

Comment: Peter, thanks much. I tried  this and same result. Since I archive my builds every month, I tried some older builds and the same error more or less shows up. The offending chapter or line number changes, but the error is the same. Do you think I may have some incorrect settings in LaTek that were not ported from my previous Mac?

Comment: I would recommend that you reinstall TeXLive2013. When I upgraded a mac last time, I had quit a bit of difficulty moving the older versions over. Other than that, try to compose a complete, yet small example that reproduces the problem and post it here.

Comment: Peter, I wanted to get back to you on your suggestions. Thanks. I tried installing a fresh version from LaTek's site and also tried copying over a known working version from another Mac; in both cases I deleted .aux files and such. This eliminated the initial errors but left me with the end command - \end{document} - somehow being deleted. Adding that back and everything works fine. Belated thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem was resolved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was fixed by reinstalling MacTeX.